# How to align a table to the top of a container?

Tags: html, css

I embedded a PHP MySQL query inside a HTML div, but the result of the loop (the table) is aligned to the bottom. Is there any way to move the table to the top of the div? This is the code:

```
<div style="background-color:yellow; display:inline-table; float:left; max-width:90%; height:auto; text-align:top; left:0; right:0; margin:auto; position:absolute;">
<?php
$agent = $_COOKIE['user'];
$server = "*******";
$user = "*******";
$pass = "*******";
$baza = "balkandi_order";
$con = mysqli_connect($server, $user, $pass, $baza) or die("conexiune    nereusita");
$sql= "SELECT * FROM tab_order WHERE agent='$agent'";
$rezultat = mysqli_query($con, $sql);
echo '<table cellpadding="5" cellspacing="0" margin-top="0" max-width="0%" margin="auto" border="1px">';
echo '<tr><th>Data</th><th>Agent</th><th>Product</th><th>Quantity</th></tr>';
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($rezultat)) {
    echo '<tr>';
    echo '<td>';
    echo $row['data'];
    echo '</td>';
    echo '<td>';
    echo $row['agent'];
    echo '</td>';
    echo '<td>';
    echo $row['product'];
    echo '</td>';
    echo '<td>';
    echo $row['qty'];
    echo '</td>';
    echo '</tr>';
    echo "<br>";
} 
echo "</table>";
mysqli_close($con);
?>
</div>
```

Comment: Could you please post a screenshot of the behaviour. Also the `echo "<br>"` may be causing some issues, it is broken syntax.

Comment: Since you're asking about html and css, please provide code samples of those - reading through php code is unnecessarily more complex than simply providing the html output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*If you don't care about learning how to improve, jump ahead to Step 3 and ignore the rest. I do encourage you to read the whole thing, though!*

### Step 1: Clean up

This code is a mess and will be a pain to change if you ever need to touch it again. Split it into pieces. First we extract the CSS:

**style.css**:

```
.container {
   background-color: yellow; 
   display: inline-table; 
   float: left;
   max-width: 90%;
   height: auto;
   text-align: top;
   left: 0;
   right: 0;
   margin: auto;
   position: absolute;
}
.container table {
   max-width: 0;
   border: 1px #000 solid;
   border-collapse: collapse;
}
.container table td {
   padding: 5px;
}
```

**template.php**:

```
<div class="container">
   <table>
      <tr>
         <th>Data</th>
         <th>Agent</th>
         <th>Product</th>
         <th>Quantity</th>
      </tr>
      <?php foreach ($tableEntries as $row): ?>
      <tr>
         <td><?php echo $row['data'] ?></td>
         <td><?php echo $row['agent'] ?></td>
         <td><?php echo $row['product'] ?></td>
         <td><?php echo $row['qty'] ?></td>
      </tr>
      <?php endforeach ?>
   </table>
</div>
```

**index.php:**

```
<?php
$agent = $_COOKIE['user'];
$server = "*******";
$user = "*******";
$pass = "*******";
$baza = "balkandi_order";
$con = mysqli_connect($server, $user, $pass, $baza) or die("conexiune    nereusita");
$sql= "SELECT * FROM tab_order WHERE agent='$agent'";
$rezultat = mysqli_query($con, $sql);
$tableEntries = array();
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($rezultat)) {
   $tableEntries[] = $row;
}
include("template.php");
```

Looks much better, doesn't it? Everything has its place now and you can actually see what's happening.

### Step 2: Fixing important issues

You are using MySQLi, which is good. But you are not using it correctly. You use a value from a cookie and hand it over directly to your database. That makes your application vulnerable to SQL injection attacks, because anybody can modify a cookie and put malicious code in there. So, let's fix this by using a prepared statement:

**index.php:**

```
<?php
// skipping the variable declarations (see above)
$con = mysqli_connect($server, $user, $pass, $baza) or die("conexiune    nereusita");
// prepare a statement with a placeholder for the agent variable
$stmt = mysqli_prepare("
   SELECT data, agent, product, qty
   FROM   tab_order
   WHERE  agent = ?");
// now we set the value for the placeholder
$stmt->bind_param('s', $agent);
$stmt->execute();
$rezultat = $stmt->get_result();
$tableEntries = array();
while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
   $tableEntries[] = $row;
}
include("template.php");
```

### Step 3: Fixing the styling

Now that we have an overview of what you are doing, let's check why your table is aligned differently to what you want. Are you really sure that you need all of these CSS properties? I doubt it. From what I can see, you need almost none of it. But you have not provided any more information an where this is used, what is surrounding it and so on. Therefore, I might be completely wrong here. Anyway, let's adapt the stylesheet:

**style.css:**

```
.container {
   background-color: yellow; 
   display: block; 
   float: left;
   max-width: 90%;
   margin: auto;
}
.container table {
   border: 1px #000 solid;
   border-collapse: collapse;
}
.container table td {
   padding: 5px;
}
```

### Step 4: Enlightenment

I hope you noticed how much difference it can make to actually take a moment to properly structure an application, even a small one. It allows you to clearly focus on problems rather than dealing with finding the right place to fix something. Also, please take some time to learn more details about the technologies you are using. In your original code there were quite a few incorrect elements like the non-existing HTML attribute `max-width`. It will make your life a lot easier, if you sit down to learn the basics.

Comment: Hello. Thank you very, very much! Your solution works perfectly! Btw, I am brand new in this area and I am trying to learn all by my self html, css, php, mysql. Thank you for your help, I owe you a beer when you will come in Bucharest :))!

Comment: Well, good luck. You entered a world of joy and pain. :D Regarding PHP I can highly recommend [PHP the right way](http://www.phptherightway.com/). I'm not a frontend developer, so I'm not clear on HTML and CSS resources, but the [Mozilla Developer Network](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/) is always a good place to go. :)

Answer (score 0):

Ok,

try

```css
div {
  background-color:yellow;
  display:inline-table;
  float:left;
  max-width:90%;
  height:auto;
  text-align:top;
  left:0;
  right:0;
  margin:auto;
  position:absolute;
 }
 
 table th,
 table td {
   height:200px;
   vertical-align: middle;
 }
```

```html
<div>
<table cellpadding="5" cellspacing="0" margin-top="0" max-width="0%" margin="auto" border="1px">
    <tr>
        <th>Data</th>
        <th>Agent</th>
        <th>Product</th>
        <th>Quantity</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            echo $row['data'];
        </td>
        <td>
            echo $row['agent'];
        </td>
        <td>
            echo $row['product'];
        </td>
        <td>
            echo $row['qty'];
        </td>
    </tr>
    <br>
</table>
</div>
```

Comment: Yes, this time table is positioned at the top of div, but as long the loop is missing, I have only one registration (in db there are around 20 registration that match query). Thank you, I am a step closer!